# Do li-po batteries need esd protection?

Tags: batteries, esd, lithium, lithium-polymer

I bought some li-po batteries and they were in antistatic bags. They have protection circuits. Do they need esd protection (grey bags)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: The protection circuitry likely uses MOSFETs, which generally have a sensitive gate lead. However, the way they are wired into the protection circuitry (you cannot access the gate lead) should make them all but impervious to ESD. Often resellers just use anti-static bags for anything and everything.

Comment: What they really need is Fire & Explosion proof Lipo Battery Safe Bag.. But at least your bag might hold back leaks